# require_once is not working in php 5.3.0

Tags: php, include, connection, xampp, require-once

I am working with the function require_once but keep getting errors when trying to run the page.

actually, this code is already running to public.
but, when i copy all the code to my local computer. this code is not working .
i use XAMPP 1.7.2 PHP 5.3.0.

This is my code : "db\connect.php"

```
<?
/* Connecting, selecting database */
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Could not connect : " . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("amr") or die("Could not select database" . mysql_error());
?>
```

When i call the function "connect.php" from this code :

```
<?php
require_once('db/connect.php');

$sql="SELECT * from user";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if ( $result == false ) { die(mysql_error()); }
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);

?>
```

i get this error :

```
No database selected
```

Please explain what my problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Add the link identifier in your [select_db](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php) funct.

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Could not connect : " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("amr",$link ) or die("Could not select database" . mysql_error());
```

Do the same with your query:

```
$result=mysql_query($sql,$link);
```

This could be caused by having multiple connections open on one page.

Or even better, use [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). Mysql_ is deprecated.

Comment: i use one connection only. and i already try it and get same error

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your problem is in this line:

```
mysql_select_db("amr")
```

try this:

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Could not connect : " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("amr", $link) or die("Could not select database" . mysql_error());
```

Comment: i use one connection only. and i already. try it and get same error. this code is already running in public. it just not working in my computer.

Comment: Does those exact databases exist on your xampp?

Comment: yes, of course. i was restore database.